# Is it possible to determine the kernel events that occurred between two points in time?

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel

Consider the following application. Assume `rdtsc` is a function that wraps the assembly instruction `rdtsc` and returns the current value of the cycle counter.

```
int main() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
       uint64_t start = rdtsc();
       // Do some work such as accessing memory or performing some computation.           
       uint64_t end = rdtsc();
   }
}
```

Is it possible to determine what events (page faults, interrupt handlers, IPI's) happened in the kernel, on this core, in between the two timing measurements?

For context, I'm trying to chase down tail latency on the order of 50-100 us.